# Theoretical calculation for deuterium tritium fusion

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, hadron-dynamics

How would a deuterium-tritium fusion feynmann diagram look like in terms of QHD (i.e meson exchange like eta,pi,sigma,omega,...)? I couldn't find anything online whilst this would be quite an interesting cross-section calculation.